# NSXMLParser works fine in iOS5 but not working in iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsxmlparser, nsxml

In my iOS application, i m trying to parse the below xml using NSXMLParser. I can successfully parse this xml in iOS5 but in iOS6 the parser not getting into parserdidStartElement . In iOS6 parserDidStartDocument is successfully called but not getting into any other parser delegate methods.. Is there any problem with the xml format?? How can I fix this..

```
            <RESULTS>
    <ROW>
    <COLUMN NAME="NAME">Test1</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="ANAME">testing xml1</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="PHONE">4470111</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="REMARKS"/>
    <COLUMN NAME="XCOORD_DMS">227901.58873387</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="YCOORD_DMS">391872.68493206</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="XCOORD_WGS">51.49367618</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="YCOORD_WGS">25.27912682</COLUMN>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
    <COLUMN NAME="NAME">Test2</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="ANAME">testing xml2</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="PHONE">4258444</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="REMARKS"/>
    <COLUMN NAME="XCOORD_DMS">229608.71442946</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="YCOORD_DMS">386848.18818915</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="XCOORD_WGS">51.51051535</COLUMN>
    <COLUMN NAME="YCOORD_WGS">25.23373805</COLUMN>
    </ROW>
    </RESULTS>
```

This is the code..

```
- (void) initView:(JsonObject *) pageMenu{

    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.test.in/test.xml"];

    NSXMLParser* parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];

    [parser release];

}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    NSLog (@"I have started");

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
NSLog (@"I have started");

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

NSLog (@"I have started");
}

-(void) parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

NSLog (@"I have started");
}

-(void) parserDidEndDocument: (NSXMLParser *)parser {

NSLog (@"I have started");
}
```

Comment: Phillipe.. i have pasted some code for you.. if i use other simple xmls it is getting into all the parser delegates.. the problem is only with the xml formal.. but not sure how this works perfectly in iOS6

Answer (score 1):

I found what is the problem with XML... When creating the XML it should be saved as UTF-8 without BOM.. this is the problem. After doing this issue is fixed

Comment: Uppercase or lowercase shouldn't make any difference. The problem must be somewhere else

Comment: Phillipe.. yes u are right.. I have edited the answer.. thanks for ur help

Answer (score 0):

Try this method (part of the delegate methods)

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
{
    NSLog(@"Error = %@", parseError);
}
```

I got an error on iOS 6 but not on iOS 5, but got an error message with that, where it says there is something wrong with the parsing. 
(Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=9 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 9.)").

You can btw check error codes here : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Im Still trying to figure out my own problem, but this line may help you in the right direction.

Hope you solve it!

Comment: I found a solution to my own problem - in case you maybe get the same. I changed my XML header to encoding UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1, and saved the XML file itself with UTF-8 encoding also. It's very important to save the XML file with UTF-8 encoding, and not just change the header in the XML file. 

Hope it can help someone!